# Save to SD kaart in Codenameone

Tags: codenameone, sd-card

i am developing an app with codenameone where i want to store images on my sd card. The images are stored in a zip, which i select with Filechooser. The code below is working when i choose FileSystemStorage.getInstance().FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath();
i have two questions a. What is wrong in the code? b. how can simulate writing to sd card in the simulator.

```
  public void Loadhwlwstations( ) {
  InputStream is;
     FileChooser.showOpenDialog(".zip", new ActionListener() {
             @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              if (e != null && e.getSource() != null) {
                String file = (String)e.getSource();
                FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
              try {
                  InputStream is  = fs.openInputStream(file);
                  ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(is);
                  ZipEntry entry;

                   // create a buffer to improve copy performance later.
                   byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    while ((entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                      String s = entry.getName();
              
                     String[] roots  = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getRoots();
                     String root = roots[0];
                        for (int i = 0; i < roots.length; i++) {


                            if (FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getRootType(roots[i]) == FileSystemStorage.ROOT_TYPE_SDCARD) {
                                root = roots[i];
                                   Kaarten.AuvHW.setText(     root);
                                          String outdir2 = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath();
                      String outdir = root;
                      
                      
                    //  String outdir = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath();
                      if (outdir.length() > 0) {
                          outdir = outdir  ;
                      }
                      String outpath = outdir   + "/" +  entry.getName();
                      OutputStream output = null;
                      try {
                          output = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(outpath);
                          int len = 0;
                          while ((len = zipStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                              output.write(buffer, 0, len);
                         }

                      } finally {
                          // we must always close the output file
                          if (output != null) {
                              output.close();
                          }
                      }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                      
                      
                      
                      
                
                      
                      
                      
                    } } catch (IOException ex) {
```

ex.printStackTrace();; }

```
              }      }});}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google [restricted access to the external storage](https://groups.google.com/g/codenameone-discussions/c/kux6P22NQuo/m/m6zMA_51BAAJ).  This means that even if your app asks for permissions it can't write everywhere. It can only write to a specific file hierarchy.

For reading files I suggest using the [file chooser](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-filechooser) API. You can write them using the share API in the `CN` class.

In the past some people reported that you could write to specific folders within the SD card. But I can't find those reports in my searches. It relies on very OS specific behavior.